# Streaming Knapsack Problem

Tags: algorithms, optimization, streaming-algorithm, online-algorithms

I want to implement efficiently "streaming Knapsack" problem in java.

The problem is I have a stream input of integer data coming continuously for example -1, 2, 9, 5, 5, 11, 1 -3,...

The question is to find the first "k" elements in which their sum is "n>0". for example k=3 and n=12, 
then the solution is: ...,2,...,5, 5.

I found an answer in http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/05/15/streaming-knapsack/2/ 
as: (It is mainly for positive Integer Values)

But looking for simpler one! Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by simpler ones? Faster ones? Ones requiring less memory? Ones easier to program?

Comment: faster and simpler to code

Comment: I'm not sure that there is any faster simple solution (or any faster solution at all), and I don't think that this dynamic programming solution is that hard to code, even in Java.

Comment: You meantion you get a "stream" of data. Does that impose any restrictions on the algorithm? For example, does it have unlimited memory?

Comment: yes, it should be memory efficient.